# Set Style for wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I have added three menus to my template, but I am having trouble displaying the styles and cannot specify the styles for them. Here are the three menus:

```
function register_the_menu(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'header_menu_fadev' => __( 'HeaderMenu', 'fadev'),
        'top_menu_fadev'  => __( 'TopMenu', 'fadev' ),
        'footer_menu_fadev'  => __( 'FooterMenu', 'fadev' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_the_menu');
```

**menu 1 (Header menu with DropDown):**

```
<nav class="header__nav">
   <ul class="align-items-center d-flex">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown mx-2">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"href="#" role="button" aria expanded="false">Home</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="mx-2"> <a href="#">Advertise</a> </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

**menu 2-3(Top and Footer menu):**

```
<nav class="section__left__nav">
   <ul class="align-items-center d-flex flex-wrap">
      <li class="mx-2 my-2 my-lg-0"> <a href="#" class="text-white">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I cannot use the styles that I have defined. Can you please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

```
if (has_nav_menu('top_menu')) {
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                theme_location'  => 'footer_menu',
                'menu_id'      => 'menu-1',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul  class="align-items-center d-flex flex-wrap"><li class="mx-2 my-2 my-lg-0"><a class="text-white">%3$s</a></li></ul>',
                'fallback_cb'     => false,
                )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `register_nav_menus`  you defined footer menu like this:

```
'footer_menu_fadev'  => __( 'FooterMenu', 'fadev' ),
```

And in `wp_nav_menu` for `theme_location` you should change your param to this

```
theme_location'  => 'footer_menu_fadev' // not this 'footer_menu',
```

Comment: Thank you.

I made a mistake in the codes I put on my website! Now I have an issue with styling the menu. How can I apply my own classes?

Comment: If code works now, you have set an `menu_id`, you can attach CSS to that ID `#menu-1`